# C++ GLFW3 input handling

Tags: c++, opengl, lambda, callback, glfw

So I've been working on a game engine using OpenGL + GLFW. Originally I had been using the LWJGL wrappers and using Java. I've decided to port my codebase to C++. I had been making use of the "glfwSetCursorPosCallback" function via a lambda like so:

```
//Java:
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(win, (window, xpos, ypos) -> {
    engine.onCursorMoved(xpos, ypos);
});
```

Doing this allowed me to tie together all of the different "events" in the Engine class and keep the GLFW setup code + the raw update loop separate from the rest of the engine code. Leaving the Engine class nice and clean.

I would like to do the same thing using C++ however the following is invalid:

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, [engine](GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y) {
    engine.onCursorMoved(x, y);
});
```

With C++ lambdas you cannot pass anything in the "[]" block if the lambda is being used as a function parameter.

So I was looking into it a bit more a on-top of that initial problem I also read that the performance was worse using lambdas.

So I tried passing the member function as the parameter instead:

```
// I changed "onCursorMoved" use the proper parameter signature
// "onCursorMoved(GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y)"
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, engine.onCursorMoved);
```

Trying this also failed as you cannot pass an instanced classes member function as a parameter to glfwSetCursorPosCallback.

So I ask, what approach should I take? Is there ways to get around the lambda/member function limitations, or some totally different approach to this that I'm completely missing?

P.S. - I'm quite out of practice with C++ so please forgive me if the answer is blatantly obvious.

Edit: To help illustrate/clarify what I'm trying to achieve, this is the Engine.h based on my previous Java version.

```
class Engine {
private:
    //member variables for scene graph, etc
public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();
public:
    void onWindowResized(int width, int height);
    void onCursorMoved(double x, double y);
    void onUpdate(float timeStep);
    void onRender();
};
```

Basically the different functions prefixed with "on" are fired off by the GLFW callbacks/loop in main, among potentially other things. Is this approach doable, somehow, or is there a better way of doing this in C++, coming from Java where everything is in Objects, is this mindset flawed for this situation?

Comment: Some good info on [GLFW Docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#cursor_pos)

Comment: @Carl Yeah, I had been looking in the docs. I knew about the static function approach but that doesn't help tie the event into my engine class as my engine class is not static, and I don't think it should have to be. As for the `glfwGetCursorPos` option, I can't remember where In the docs I read it, but it was along the lines of "use the callback instead of the polling where ever possible"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) to set the `Engine` instance a given window should call callbacks on.

Then in the (capture-less) lambdas you can call [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06) with `window`, cast the `void*` to `Engine*`, and call the appropriate member function.

Example:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cstdlib>

class Engine
{
public:
    void onCursorPos( double x, double y )
    {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    double mX, mY;
};

int main()
{
    if( !glfwInit() )
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1 );
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL );

    Engine engine;
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer( window, &engine );

    glfwSetCursorPosCallback( window, []( GLFWwindow* window, double x, double y )
    {
        Engine* engine = static_cast<Engine*>( glfwGetWindowUserPointer( window ) );
        engine->onCursorPos( x, y );
    } );

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glfwSwapInterval( 1 );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glClearColor( engine.mX / 640.0, engine.mY / 480.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow( window );
    glfwTerminate();
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: that looks perfect. One quick question, if using the `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` approach, would it be more performant to use a static function instead of a lambda? Or do they essentially compile into the same thing?

Comment: @HexCrown: I'm pretty sure the lambda in this case is going to end up as syntactic sugar around what will amount to a static function.  You can use [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) to compare assembly output if you want to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

just put the name of the callback function:

```
//callbacks header file
void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);

//GLFW init function
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursor_position_callback);
```

Comment: I was going to do that however the issue is that the "Engine engine;" needs to be outside of the scope to be usable. So I made Engine take the GLFWwindow as a constructor param like so: `Engine::Engine(GLFWwindow* window)` and tried 
 `glfwSetCursorPosCallback(m_window, onCursorMoved);` within the Engine constructor, same issue as I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: If the idea is to have all callbacks in one function maybe is a good a idea to deal only with one, for example the callbacks generated by the Engine class and query what you need from the glfw

Comment: please see "Edit" at end of original post for a clarifying example.

Comment: Oh, I see, for the callback function you need to have the parameter of the GLFW context, then a pointer to the function inside your engine class instance should work, try it. If doesn't work i am afraid i can't help much more..