# Error: request for member 'display' in 'square', which is of non-class type 'GameBoxes::Box<double>()'

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make the video game Snake using C++ and OpenGL so I can implement a machine learning algorithm to play it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace GameBoxes
{
    template<class T>
    class Box
    {
    public:
        Box(); //Initialize with a square size of 10 in center and color white.

        void display(void);

    private:
        T colorBlue;
        T colorRed;
        T colorGreen;
        T vertex1Pos1;
        T vertex1Pos2;
        T thirdForm1;
        T vertex2Pos1;
        T vertex2Pos2;
        T thirdForm2;
        T vertex3Pos1;
        T vertex3Pos2;
        T thirdForm3;
        T vertex4Pos1;
        T vertex4Pos2;
        T thirdForm4;

    };
} //GameBoxes


namespace GameBoxes
{
    template <class T>
    Box<T>::Box() : colorBlue(0.0), colorRed(0.0), colorGreen(0.0), vertex1Pos1(2.0),
                    vertex1Pos2(4.0), thirdForm1(0.0), vertex2Pos1(8.0), vertex2Pos2(4.0),
                    thirdForm2(0.0), vertex3Pos1(8.0), vertex3Pos2(6.0), thirdForm3(0.0),
                    vertex4Pos1(2.0), vertex4Pos2(6.0), thirdForm4(0.0)
    {
    }

    template <class T>
    void Box<T>::display(void)
    {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glColor3f(colorBlue, colorRed, colorGreen);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
         glVertex3f(vertex1Pos1, vertex1Pos2, thirdForm1);
         glVertex3f(vertex2Pos1, vertex2Pos2, thirdForm2);
         glVertex3f(vertex3Pos1, vertex3Pos2, thirdForm3);
         glVertex3f(vertex4Pos1, vertex4Pos2, thirdForm4);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }
} // GameBoxes

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    int windowPos1, windowPos2, windowSize1, windowSize2;
    std::cout << "Please enter WinPos1, WinPos2, WinSize1 and WinSize2\n";
    std::cin  >> windowPos1 >> windowPos2 >> windowSize1, windowSize2;

    glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(windowPos1, windowPos2);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowSize1, windowSize2);
    glutCreateWindow ("square");

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);       // black background
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);        // setup viewing projection
    glLoadIdentity();               // start with identity matrix
    glOrtho(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0, -1.0, 1.0);   // setup 10x10x2 viewing world

    GameBoxes::Box<double> square();
    glutDisplayFunc(square.display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
};
```

This gives me the error listed within the title.

The code works perfectly when I hardcode in all of the variables and remove void display(void) from the class.

I honestly don't understand why having the display function within the class causes so many problems. I'm going to try and make it a friend function.

Comment: You forgot `()` after `square.display`.

Comment: square.display() still causes the error. Okay, I'll try to edit it down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: request for member '..' in '..' which is of non-class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type)

Comment: I already looked at that question and was completely lost. Closing this question is going to leave me completely in the dark.

Comment: I suspect your intent is to use `GameBoxes::Box<double>::display` as the `glut` display function.  But `GameBoxes::Box<double>::display` is a non-static member of `GameBoxes::Box<double>` and, therefore, not convertible to a `void (*func)(void)` as required by [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you fix the bad `square` declaration (should be `GameBoxes::Box<double> square`, notice the lack of parenthesis) you're not going to be able to pass a C++ member-function pointer into an API that expects a C function pointer.

You'll have to write a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk#Interoperability) that's usable as a regular function pointer such as a [capture-less lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233484/c-glfw3-input-handling/50235276#50235276) or a static member function.

If you're using FreeGLUT you can use[`glutSetWindowData()`/`glutGetWindowData()`](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h#L176) to set which class instance to use on a per-window basis and grab+cast in the thunk:

```
glutSetWindowData( &square );
glutDisplayFunc( []()
{
    auto instance = static_cast< GameBoxes::Box<double>* >( glutGetWindowData() );
    instance->display();
} );
```

All together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

namespace GameBoxes
{
template<class T>
class Box
{
public:
    void display( void );
};
} //GameBoxes

namespace GameBoxes
{
template <class T>
void Box<T>::display( void )
{
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );       // black background
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glColor3f( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
    glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.0,  0.5 );
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
} // GameBoxes

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );

    int windowPos1 = 0, windowPos2 = 0, windowSize1 = 400, windowSize2 = 400;
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowPosition( windowPos1, windowPos2 );
    glutInitWindowSize( windowSize1, windowSize2 );
    glutCreateWindow( "square" );

    GameBoxes::Box<double> square;

    glutSetWindowData( &square );
    glutDisplayFunc( []()
    {
        auto instance = static_cast< GameBoxes::Box<double>* >( glutGetWindowData() );
        instance->display();
    } );
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line...

```
GameBoxes::Box<double> square();  // a func declaration, but I get it
```

To...

```
GameBoxes::Box<double> square; // calls the default constructor anyway.
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix that bug. A lot of the advice is starting to make sense now. The error just changed to "Improper use of void function"

Comment: @Kalkirin, yes, you would have pass the appropriate function; however, genpfault seems to have a viable idea with the api's you are using.  You could also just have a function wrapper that will use your class; but now we get into a bigger design discussion.